# In Inkscape, is there a way to apply an alpha mask or gradient over another color gradient?

Tags: inkscape, transparency, gradient

I have an object that I've applied a linear gradient to:

[image]

that I would like to fade to transparent at the edges:

[image]

But I do not know how to do this, given that inkscape doesn't let you apply two gradients to one object (I would like to apply a radial alpha gradient over the linear color gradient). I've accomplished the look here by just using a white elliptical gradient on a new shape, which surrounds the colored shape, plus a white background. But that's obviously not what I want; I want the shape to have a fully transparent background.

Is there a way to achieve this with some kind of Clip & Mask? Or something else?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Top left is your image (actually a screenshot). Top right is a rectangle with gradient fill. In the bottom the gradient rectangle has been dragged onto your shape, both were selected and a mask was set (=Object > Mask > set).

Mask makes the underlying object transparent. White=no change, grey=partially transparent, black=fully transparent.

BEWARE: The parts are still selectable. One can easily move accidentally the mask and the shape apart. Learn to use the Objects panel for reliable selections.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'll offer an improvement though; the way you did it leaves the original shape fully opaque only at the very center (the gradient's slope is very gradual). To fix this, instead of using a radial gradient fill on the white ellipse, I just blurred it.

Comment: @Anonymous OK. As well one can insert a white gradient mid stop to extend the 100% opaque area.  This gives more control than blurring a white shape.

Comment: True, even better